# How to loop through and scrape data from collapsibles on a website using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

pretty beginner coder here but I am trying to scrape email addresses of tux rental places from this website (https://www.jimsformalwear.com/stores) using Selenium. The email addresses are displayed once the 'Details' link is clicked. I am able to loop through and click details under each stores' name but am only able to pull the email address of the first store. Any help is appreciated

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

ser = Service("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)

s.get("https://www.jimsformalwear.com/stores")
search = s.find_element(by=By.ID, value='address')
search.send_keys("Des Moines, IA")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(3)

stores = []
email = []

store_names = s.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='store-name')
for name in store_names:
    stores.append(name.text)

link_details = s.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'DETAILS')
for n in link_details:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(s, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'DETAILS')))
        n.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        emails = s.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='store-email.store-contact-item')
        email.append(emails.text)
        time.sleep(3)
    except:
        s.quit()

s.quit()

dict1 = {
    "Store Name": stores,
    "Email": email
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)

print(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A note on debugging: when using `try...except`, debugging is easier if you print the exception - something like

```py
try:
    ### CODE THAT MIGHT RAISE EXCEPTION ###
except Exception as err:
    print(str(err))
    #########  HANDLE  EXCEPTION  #########
```

that way, you might have a better idea of what went wrong.

---

You're not targeting the right elements for `EC.element_to_be_clickable` and `emails = s.find_element` - in both cases, you're just targeting the first element of that type when you should be using a more specific identifying attribute like `id` or `data-target` or `data-actnum`. Also, you need to scroll to the "DETAILS" button so the click doesn't fall on something else for the last items (which is something I discovered due to `print(str(err))`). So, your `try...except` block should be changed to

```py
    try:
        dtarget = n.get_attribute('data-target')
        dSel = f'a[data-target="{dtarget}"]'
        eSel = f'{dtarget} .store-email'

        s.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", n)
        WebDriverWait(s, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, dSel)))
        n.click()
        time.sleep(3)

        emails = s.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, eSel)
        email.append(emails.text)
        time.sleep(3)
    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))
        s.quit()
        break # no point looping again after s.quit()
```

When I run it with the changes above, the `email` list ends up as

```py
['monica.bridalboutique@gmail.com', 'angelicasdesign@gmail.com', 'rbeamer@thetuxshopdm.com', 'staceysbridal@gmail.com', 'katie@somethingbluebride.com', 'info@affinitybridals.com', 'backwardsboutique16830@gmail.com']
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thank you Driftr95, it is working perfectly for me. I really appreciate it and thanks for the debugging tip